# how to get next row data in gridview?

Tags: c#, search, gridview

i want to get next data in gridview, the thing is when i use break; it totally out of loop, but when i dont use break; it otomatically call the last row data of the text that i type.

```
  private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            var row = gridView1.GetDataRow(i);
            var genre = row["genre"].ToString();

            if (genre.IndexOf(textBox8.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            {
                gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = i;                
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

if i dont use break it will select the last data with 'ba' = basketball.
what i want is when i click next it select ballet and stop, and when i click next button again it select basketball
[image: imge1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an `int` variable to store the current iteration of loop:

```
int iteration=0;

private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        for (int i = iteration; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            var row = gridView1.GetDataRow(i);
            var genre = row["genre"].ToString();

            if (genre.IndexOf(textBox8.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            {
                gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = i;
                iteration=i+1;                
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

And on Find button you can reset iteration to 0

Comment: You could also use `int i = gridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex + 1`. This would search after the selected row no matter if you selected the row with the mouse or searched beforehand. The problem with this solution is if you click on Martial arts then search for the next 'ba' you get Ballet even though it comes beforehand. So this implementation works unless you allow selecting with the mouse and want the Next button to take that into consideration.

Comment: well sure it works.
the thing is when i type 'ba' and click find the output is = ballet, but when i try to click next the output stil = ballet but when i try to click it again the output is basketball, how to continue the search after click find so the first click on next it was basketball ?

Comment: @Lithium i cant even call selected or row index ==

Comment: @DavidChopperField I'm not sure what you are asking. I was saying in the for loop you can set `i` to `gridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex + 1` which really you can also use `gridview.SelectedIndex` so the for loop would be `for (int i = gridview.SelectedIndex + 1; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)`

Comment: i mean when i type those like selectedrow and row index, it got red underline. the auto text for selectedrow was selected row count and when i it, the next after .(dot) was compare to ,equal, and etc

Comment: @Lithium mmh, thanks for ur suggestion.. and i have modify it. its true what u said. after  i search martial art and i retype ba to search it give me basketball instead of ballet.. do you have any suggest?